# How to return json key as INT and values (array) as an array in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, plpgsql

I have created a json variable **VDN** which is like so

```
{"80001": ["6", "9"], "80002": ["2", "6", "10"], "80004": ["4", "10", "8"]}
```

I have created a table in which the keys and values separate in two different columns as **Varchar**.

```
drop function if exists aa_Dev.VDN();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_dev.VDN()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$

begin

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aa_dev.sdg_vdn;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aa_dev.sdg_vdn (
        VDN VARCHAR,
        skills VARCHAR
    );

    INSERT INTO aa_dev.sdg_vdn(VDN, skills)
    select t.*
    from aa_dev.sdg_metadata m
    cross join json_each_text(m.VDN) as t(VDN, "values");
      

   
end

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So instead of varchar the data types I want should be now

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aa_dev.sdg_vdn (
    VDN INT,
    skills INT[]
);
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL? I have tried using json_populate_record instead of json_each_text as it can return any data type but that did not work either.

Comment: Unrelated, but: creating a new table each time a function is invoked is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need a multi step approach: first extract all key/value pairs from the JSON and then convert that back into a JSONB value which in turn can be converted to a record type:

```
insert into sdg_vdn (vdn, skills)
select (jsonb_populate_record(null::sdg_vdn, to_jsonb(t))).*
from jsonb_each('{"80001": ["6", "9"], "80002": ["2", "6", "10"], "80004": ["4", "10", "8"]}'::jsonb) as t(vdn, skills)
```

The intermediate step using `to_jsonb(t)` is necessary to convert the key/value pair that is returned from `jsonb_each()` back into a single JSON value - which then can be converted to the record type of the target table. The `(...).*` is necessary to extract the columns of that record.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3f9225d1231992594cd08d05927a1121)

Comment: Why are you converting json to jsonb?

Comment: @Chloe: I am not. I am converting the _row_ (with two columns) back into a single json value. (I explained that: "*the intermediate step using to_jsonb() ...*"

Comment: I also want to reference the json variable directly from another table, not hard code it as a string. from jsonb_each(aa_dev.sdg_metadata.vdns::jsonb) as t(vdn, skills); but it gives error ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "sdg_metadata"